# mysqi extension is missing

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I had uncommented the 'extension=php_mysqli.dll' in the PHP config file but I'm still getting the error message that my mySQLi extension is missing. What else do I verify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After restarting your web service, check PHP info:

```
phpinfo();
```

Does the extension appear there?  If so, it loaded correctly.  If not, you are likely missing the DLL, or have the wrong extension path.

Look for something like this:
[image: mysqli extension]

Comment: I commented both 

extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll

in my PHP config file (by removing the semi-colons), yet my phpinfo(); is not changing. There's no mysql or a mysqli in the phpinfo(); that is, before and after the commenting/uncommenting. I also checked in the ext folder, I have both the DLLs present. How do I check if the path is incorrect?

Comment: I think I found the problem but not the solution. Despite whatever path I give to the extension dir in php config file, it still shows up as C:\PHP in the phpinfo(); I've also checked that it's accessing the right config file as shown by phpinfo();

What do I do now?

Comment: Got it! Kept at it, restarted servers repeatedly and then got it! Thanks Brad!

Comment: No problem!  Please consider accepting this answer if it solved the problem for you.  (Check-mark next to vote up/down buttons.)

Comment: It says I need some reputation to vote up. :/ But nonetheless, I'll remember to vote when I get there.

Comment: @Ganesh, don't worry about that.  Just click the check mark to accept this as the answer.  That way when others come here to this question, they will be able to easily spot the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else using ubuntu. I ran into this problem on a fresh ubuntu installation. I solved it by adding this line to  php.ini.

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

My php.ini was located @ /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error while clicking on phpmyadmin and tried all possible solns povided in google. i tried with wamp  and then reinstalling xamp.neither didnt and looked at the php.ini file.but everything was perfect. Later i realised i was selecting google chrome as my default browser while installing xamp. but then i tried opening localhost with Internet Explorer and everyhtng was fine.

Thanks 
Sobbosanchi

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. I was trying to install it with firefox and it did not work. Then I read your advice and changed to IE, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Was on this problem for hours...

**Solved** it by changing `extension_dir = "ext"` to `extension_dir = "C:/PHP-5.5.13/ext"`

Seems like it doesn't like relative pathing...