# mysqli.dll and mysql.dll not mentioned in phpinfo

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728330/mysqi-extension-is-missing) 
and it didn't really help.

My `php.ini` file (http://www.edisk.cz/stahni/09234/php.ini_69.47KB.html) contains the correct path of `ext` directory.

While my `ext` directory contains a `php_mysql.dll` and `php_mysqli.dll` libraries, there's not a word of that in my `phpinfo`.

Is there a way to make it right?

http://prntscr.com/3707m

This is my error produced by `php.exe`.

Comment: Good grace. Did I really write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have two separate php.ini files - one for your web server, one for the command line interface.
Make sure you're editing the correct file; Run:

```
php.exe --ini
```

which will give you output similar to the one below:

```
C:\>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Path\To\Your\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Now, edit the php.ini file and make sure that not only the following lines are un-commented:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

but also this one (which, according to the file you've posted, you have commented out at the moment):

```
; extension_dir = "ext"
```

The above one should be configured to point to your `ext` directory, where the php_mysql.dll file is stored. Like this (remember about double quotes):

```
extension_dir="C:\Path\To\Your\php\ext"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it helps. I don't know how, but it works! I did all these things again and it works! Thank you!